# How to combine "react-native-contacts" and "react-native-communications"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, development-environment

I would like to combine the "**React-Native-Contacts**" Library (github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts) and "**React-Native-Communications**" to directly select and call my contacts already registered in the Directory of My phone. The problem is that I don't know how to do this by modifying the "OnPress" props of "App.js" code from the "**React-Native-Contacts**" library which is "***onPress={() => Contacts.openExistingContact(contact, () => { })}***" by assigning that of the Components "**Communications**" which calls to "**Communications.phonecall('0123456789', true)**". The goal is therefore to modify the telephone number "***0123456789***" by the selected Contact from my Mobile Phone Directory.

**Here is my complete Code for accessing Mobile Phone Contacts and based on "react-native-contacts":**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import Contacts from "react-native-contacts";

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.search = this.search.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      searchPlaceholder: "Search"
    };

    Contacts.iosEnableNotesUsage(true);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
        title: "Contacts",
        message: "This app would like to view your contacts."
      }).then(() => {
        this.loadContacts();
      });
    } else {
      this.loadContacts();
    }
  }

  loadContacts() {
    Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
      if (err === "denied") {
        console.warn("Permission to access contacts was denied");
      } else {
        this.setState({ contacts });
      }
    });

    Contacts.getCount(count => {
      this.setState({ searchPlaceholder: `Search ${count} contacts` });
    });
  }

  search(text) {
    const phoneNumberRegex = /\b[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{2,6}[)]?[-\s\.]?[-\s\/\.0-9]{3,15}\b/m;
    const emailAddressRegex = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/i;
    if (text === "" || text === null) {
      this.loadContacts();
    } else if (phoneNumberRegex.test(text)) {
      Contacts.getContactsByPhoneNumber(text, (err, contacts) => {
        this.setState({ contacts });
      });
    } else if (emailAddressRegex.test(text)) {
      Contacts.getContactsByEmailAddress(text, (err, contacts) => {
        this.setState({ contacts });
      });
    } else {
      Contacts.getContactsMatchingString(text, (err, contacts) => {
        this.setState({ contacts });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            paddingLeft: 100,
            paddingRight: 100,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("./logo.png")}
            style={{
              aspectRatio: 6,
              resizeMode: "contain"
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <SearchBar
          searchPlaceholder={this.state.searchPlaceholder}
          onChangeText={this.search}
        />
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {this.state.contacts.map(contact => {
            return (
              <ListItem
                leftElement={
                  <Avatar
                    img={
                      contact.hasThumbnail
                        ? { uri: contact.thumbnailPath }
                        : undefined
                    }
                    placeholder={getAvatarInitials(
                      `${contact.givenName} ${contact.familyName}`
                    )}
                    width={40}
                    height={40}
                  />
                }
                key={contact.recordID}
                title={`${contact.givenName} ${contact.familyName}`}
                description={`${contact.company}`}
                onPress={() => Contacts.openExistingContact(contact, () => { })}
                onDelete={() =>
                  Contacts.deleteContact(contact, () => {
                    this.loadContacts();
                  })
                }
              />
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

const getAvatarInitials = textString => {
  if (!textString) return "";

  const text = textString.trim();

  const textSplit = text.split(" ");

  if (textSplit.length <= 1) return text.charAt(0);

  const initials =
    textSplit[0].charAt(0) + textSplit[textSplit.length - 1].charAt(0);

  return initials;
};
```

Help me solve this puzzle by successfully combining the two Libraries  "**React-Native-Contacts**" (github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts) and "**React-Native-Communications**" because this Tutorial that explains how to use "**React-Native-Communications**" (aboutreact.com/make-phone-call-send-sms-or-email-using-react-native-communication/) does not detail how to do it work with the contacts of our mobile phone.

Help me please to add "**React-Native-Communications**" ***phoneCall*** function into my "**React-Native-Contacts**" code above.

Answer (score 0):

implying your contacts have only 1 number stored, or if there are multiple: you want to call the first number, you can simply use:

`onPress={() => Communications.phonecall(contact.phoneNumbers[0].number, true)}`

if a contact has more than 1 number stored (for example work/home/mobile/...), you must implement some logic so you can choose which one. show a prompt with all numbers listed, for example